# if $g$ is a lie algebra what is $g^*$?

Tags: definition, lie-algebras

Iam trying to learn what a coadjoint orbit is but I can't since everywhere I look  the definition involves $g^*$.Something that I googled and didn't find anything. I am not even sure what $g^*$. Is it just the dual vector space of our the vector space $V$ of $g$. Is it somehow a lie algebra?, or even maybe even something dual to the notion of lie algebra. Can anyone explain
Thanks in advance

Comment: $g^*$ is the dual space of $g$. The algebra $g$ acts on $g^*$ via the coadjoint action, so $g^*$ is a $g$-module. The Lie group $G$ which has $g$ as Lie algebra also acts on $g^*$, and the *coadjoint orbits* are the orbits of $G$ acting on $g^*$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Lie algebra ${\frak g}$ is in particular a vector space, and $\frak{g}^*$ denotes the dual vector space.

It does not come with any canonical Lie algebra structure, we just think of it as a vector space.

Comment: It has a Poisson bracket, though.

Answer (score 1):

Here $\mathfrak{g}$ also denotes the adjoint module, given by the adjoint representation $ad\colon \mathfrak{g}\rightarrow \mathfrak{gl}(\mathfrak{g})$. It is a $\mathfrak{g}$-module. Its dual module is denoted by $\mathfrak{g}^{\ast}$. So I would answer the title question as follows:

"If $\mathbb{g}$ is a Lie algebra - then $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{g}^{\ast}$ are $\mathfrak{g}$-modules".